# Access DB Compare Column to column from table

Tags: sql, compare, contains, sql-like

I have a table. It has a few columns.. 2 of which that I am manipulating.

(table-material.codes) Code_id and (table-material.description) Description_id

Code_id is a look up from a table which has material names and their codeID#
Description_id is a look up from a table which has material descriptions and I have added a field that looks up the Code_ID into it.

In this table these are drop down lists that you can choose the full description of what you are ordering.

so code idea 1=elbow description= 90 degree blah blah.

I want to use either contains or like to compare description_id against code_id so when I select Elbows it will give me descriptions for elbows not the full list of materials.

Everything I see has contains or like (some text) not another field with its multiple choices.

TABLE-- Material_ordered

FIELD:CODE_ID_

SELECT [Material-Codes].*, [Material-Codes].CATEGORIES_ FROM [Material-Codes] ORDER BY [Material-Codes].CATEGORIES_;

FIELD:DESC_ID_

SELECT [Material-Description].*, [Material-Description].DESC_ID_ FROM [Material-Description] ORDER BY [Material-Description].[MATERIAL DESCRIPTION];

Comment: Elbows is not a category?

Comment: When you have multiple types of elbows it is?

Category elbows
DESCRIPTION

ELBOW, 45 DEG BW SCH 40S SS SA-403 GR. WP304/304L
ELBOW, 45 DEG SW SS SA-182 GR. F304/304L 3000LB
ELBOW, 45 DEG. THRD SCH 40S SS SA-182 GR. F304/304L
ELBOW, 90 DEG LR B.W., 10S, S.S., SA-403 GR. WP304/304L
ELBOW, 90 DEG LR THRD., 800S, S.S., SA-403 GR. WP304/304L
ELBOW, 90 DEG SW SS SA-182 GR. F304/304L 3000LB
ELBOW, 90 DEG THRD SS SA-182 GR F304/304L 3000LB

ELBOW, 90 DEG. L.R. , REDUCER, B.W., 40S, S.S., SA-403 GR. WP304/304L

ELBOW, 90 DEG. L.R.,SCH. 80, B.W., C.S., A-234 Gr. WPB

Comment: Select category ELBOWS, and filter your material-codes dropdown on that category?  Or do you need further refinement?  What about adding a subcategory?

Comment: They are in different tables.
Table 1 - category + code
table 2 - description + code
Table 3 - OrderKEY + category + size + description + QTY etc etc

Table 3 is editable with only table 1 and table 2 data fields 
so i need the table 3 description to filter after you choose table 3 category. So you don't choose a description for material unrelated to say.. elbows if you choose elbows.